# Postfix virtual_alias and recipient_delimiter forwarding

Tags: postfix

Help me to setup Postfix, please,
I've set recipient_delimiter to . (dot) and wanted to forward emails with the rule:

```
test.1@example.com -> mymail@example.org
test.2@example.com -> mymail@example.org
test.3@example.com -> mymail@example.org
```

and so on.

But when I send email to test.1@example.com, it forwards to mymail.1@example.org.

How I can prevent this behavior?

main.cf:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = .
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

virtual_alias_domains = example.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:10001
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender
recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:10002
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient
```

virtual:

```
@example.com mymail@example.org
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, unmatched extensions (that is the stuff to the right of your delimiter) are propagated to the right-hand side of canonical and virtual (see [the docs](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#propagate_unmatched_extensions)). So your right-hand side of an expression in virtual gets an extension, just like you see it.

So, you should either specify an exact match (that is, with extension) on the left-hand side if virtual, or remove virtual from `propagate_unmatched_extensions` by explicitly specifying it in the config file.

Comment: `propagate_unmatched_extensions = canonical, alias, forward, include` decided my problem. Thanks!